# Why does perl warn that open my $fh, $file is missing parentheses?

Tags: perl, warnings, suppress-warnings

It is my first day to perl, and I find this warning very confusing.

> Parentheses missing around "my" list at ./grep.pl line 10.

It seems

```
open FILE, $file;
```

works fine.

What is wrong with

```
open my $fh, $file;
```

Thanks!

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;

sub grep_all {
        my $pattern = shift;

        while (my $file = shift) {
                open my $fh, $file;
                while (my $line = <$fh>) {
                        if ($line =~ m/$pattern/) {
                                print $line;
                        }   
                }   
        }   
}

grep_all @ARGV;
```

Comment: Always, *always*, **always** check whether `open` succeeds!

Comment: use three argument [open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html)

Answer (score 31, accepted):

I've been hacking Perl for more than 15 years, and I admit this warning caused me to scratch my head for a minute because almost every example call to `open` in the standard Perl documentation and *nearly every Perl tutorial* in existence contains `open` with no parentheses, just like you wrote it.

You wrote this question on your first day with Perl, but you're already enabling the `strict` and `warnings` pragmata! This is an excellent start.

## False starts

An easy but dumb way to “fix” the warning is to disable all warnings. This would be a terrible move! Warnings are meant to help you.

Naïve ways to squelch the warning are abandoning the [lexical filehandle](http://www.modernperlbooks.com/mt/2010/02/a-decade-of-lexical-filehandles.html) in favor of the bad old way with a bareword

```
open FH, $file;
```

using explicit parentheses with `open`

```
open(my $fh, $file);
```

making `my`'s parentheses explicit

```
open my($fh), $file;
```

using circumscribed parentheses

```
(open my $fh, $file);
```

or using 3-argument [`open`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html).

```
open my $fh, "<", $file;
```

**I recommend *against* using any of these by themselves** because they all have a severe omission in common.

## The best approach

In general, the best way to silence this warning about missing parentheses involves adding *no parentheses!*

Always check whether `open` succeeds, *e.g.*,

```
open my $fh, $file or die "$0: open $file: $!";
```

To disable Perl's [magic open](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/open.html) and treat `$file` as the literal name of a file—important, for example, when dealing with [untrusted user input](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsec.html)—use

```
open my $fh, "<", $file or die "$0: open $file: $!";
```

Yes, both shut up the warning, but the *much more important benefit* is your program handles inevitable errors rather than ignoring them and charging ahead anyway.

Read on to understand why you got the warning, helpful hints about your next Perl program, a bit of Perl philosophy, and recommended improvements to your code. Finally, you'll see that your program doesn't require an explicit call to `open`!

## Write helpful error messages

Notice the important components of the error message passed to [`die`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/die.html):

1. the program that complained (`$0`)
2. what it tried to do (`"open $file"`)
3. why it failed (`$!`)

These special variables are documented in [perlvar](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html). Develop the habit now of including these important bits in every error message that you'll see—although not necessarily those that *users* will see. Having all of this important information will save debugging time in the future.

## Always check whether `open` succeeds!

Once again, *always* check whether `open` and other system calls succeed! Otherwise, you end up with strange errors:

```
$ ./mygrep pattern no-such-file
Parentheses missing around "my" list at ./mygrep line 10.
readline() on closed filehandle $fh at ./mygrep line 11.
```

## Explanation of Perl's warnings

Perl's warnings have further explanation in the [perldiag documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldiag.html), and enabling the [diagnostics pragma](http://perldoc.perl.org/diagnostics.html) will look up explanations of any warning that perl emits. With your code, the output is

> `$ perl -Mdiagnostics ./mygrep pattern no-such-file`
>   **Parentheses missing around "my" list at `./mygrep` line 10 (#1)**
>   (W parenthesis) You said something like
>
> ```
> my $foo, $bar = @_;
> ```
>
> when you meant
>
> ```
> my ($foo, $bar) = @_;
> ```
>
> Remember that `my`, `our`, `local` and `state` bind tighter than comma.
>
> **readline() on closed filehandle `$fh` at `./mygrep` line 11 (#2)**
>   (W closed) The filehandle you're reading from got itself closed sometime before now.  Check your control flow.

The `-Mdiagnostics` command-line option is equivalent to `use diagnostics;` in your code, but running it as above *temporarily* enables diagnostic explanations without having to modify your code itself.

Warning #2 is because `no-such-file` does not exist, but your code unconditionally reads from `$fh`.

It's puzzling that you see warning #1 at all! This is the first time I recall ever seeing it in association with a call to `open`. The 5.10.1 documentation has 52 example uses of `open` involving lexical filehandles, but only *two* of them have parentheses with `my`.

It gets curiouser and curiouser:

```
$ perl -we 'open my $fh, $file'
Name "main::file" used only once: possible typo at -e line 1.
Use of uninitialized value $file in open at -e line 1.
```

Parentheses are missing, so where's the warning?!

Adding one little semicolon, however, *does* warn about missing parentheses:

```
$ perl -we 'open my $fh, $file;'
Parentheses missing around "my" list at -e line 1.
Name "main::file" used only once: possible typo at -e line 1.
Use of uninitialized value $file in open at -e line 1.
```

Let's look in perl's source to see where the warning comes from.

```
$ grep -rl 'Parentheses missing' .
./t/lib/warnings/op
./op.c
./pod/perl561delta.pod
./pod/perldiag.pod
./pod/perl56delta.pod
```

[`Perl_localize` in op.c](https://github.com/mirrors/perl/blob/096c060c3521cdedd801e684e4308ce9cee97019/op.c#L2517)—which handles `my`, `our`, `state`, and `local`—contains the following snippet:

```
/* some heuristics to detect a potential error */
while (*s && (strchr(", \t\n", *s)))
  s++;

while (1) {
  if (*s && strchr("@$%*", *s) && *++s
       && (isALNUM(*s) || UTF8_IS_CONTINUED(*s))) {
    s++;
    sigil = TRUE;
    while (*s && (isALNUM(*s) || UTF8_IS_CONTINUED(*s)))
      s++;
    while (*s && (strchr(", \t\n", *s)))
      s++;
  }
  else
    break;
}
if (sigil && (*s == ';' || *s == '=')) {
  Perl_warner(aTHX_ packWARN(WARN_PARENTHESIS),
    "Parentheses missing around \"%s\" list",
    lex
      ? (PL_parser->in_my == KEY_our
        ? "our"
        : PL_parser->in_my == KEY_state
          ? "state"
          : "my")
      : "local");
}
```

Notice the comment on the first line. In [My Life With Spam](http://www.perl.com/pub/2000/02/spamfilter.html), Mark Dominus wrote, “Of course, this is a heuristic, which is a fancy way of saying that it doesn't work.” The heuristic in this case doesn't work either and produces a confusing warning.

The conditional

```
if (sigil && (*s == ';' || *s == '=')) {
```

explains why `perl -we 'open my $fh, $file'` doesn't warn but does with a trailing semicolon. Watch what happens for similar but nonsensical code:

```
$ perl -we 'open my $fh, $file ='
Parentheses missing around "my" list at -e line 1.
syntax error at -e line 1, at EOF
Execution of -e aborted due to compilation errors.
```

We get the warning! The 3-argument `open` case doesn't warn because `"<"` prevents `sigil` from becoming true, and the `or die ...` modifier passes muster, in obtuse terms, because the `or` token begins with a character other than `;` or `=`.

The intent of the warning appears to be providing a helpful hint for how to fix code that will otherwise produce surprising results, *e.g.*,

```
$ perl -lwe 'my $foo, $bar = qw/ baz quux /; print $foo, $bar'
Parentheses missing around "my" list at -e line 1.
Useless use of a constant in void context at -e line 1.
Use of uninitialized value $foo in print at -e line 1.
quux
```

Here, the warning *does* make sense, but the case you found is a leak in the heuristic.

## Less is more

Perl has syntactic sugar that makes writing [Unix-style filters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filter_%28Unix%29) easy, as explained in the [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#I%2fO-Operators) documentation.

> The null filehandle `<>` is special: it can be used to emulate the behavior of sed and awk. Input from `<>` comes either from standard input, or from each file listed on the command line. Here's how it works: the first time `<>` is evaluated, the `@ARGV` array is checked, and if it is empty, `$ARGV[0]` is set to `"-"`, which when opened gives you standard input. The `@ARGV` array is then processed as a list of filenames. The loop
>
> ```
> while (<>) {
>   ... # code for each line
> }
> ```
>
> is equivalent to the following Perl-like pseudo code:
>
> ```
> unshift(@ARGV, '-') unless @ARGV;
> while ($ARGV = shift) {
>   open(ARGV, $ARGV);
>   while (<ARGV>) {
>     ... # code for each line
>   }
> }
> ```

Using the null filehandle (also known as the diamond operator) makes your code behave like the Unix grep utility.

- filter each line of each file named on the command line, or
- filter each line of the standard input when given only a pattern

The diamond operator also handles at least one corner case that your code doesn't. Note below that bar is present in the input but doesn't appear in the output.

```
$ cat 0
foo
bar
baz
$ ./mygrep bar 0
Parentheses missing around "my" list at ./mygrep line 10.
```

Keep reading to see how the diamond operator improves readability, economy of expression, and correctness!

## Recommended improvements to your code

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;

die "Usage: $0 pattern [file ..]\n" unless @ARGV >= 1;

my $pattern = shift;

my $compiled = eval { qr/$pattern/ };
die "$0: bad pattern ($pattern):\n$@" unless $compiled;

while (<>) {
  print if /$compiled/;
}
```

Rather than hardcoding the path to `perl`, use `env` to respect the user's PATH.

Rather than blindly assuming the user provided at least a pattern on the command line, check that it's present or give a helpful usage guide otherwise.

Because your pattern lives in a variable, it might change. This is hardly profound, but that means the pattern may need to be recompiled each time your code evaluates `/$pattern/`, *i.e.*, for each line of input. Using [`qr//`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Regexp-Quote-Like-Operators) avoids this waste and also provides an opportunity to check that the pattern the user supplied on the command line is a valid regex.

```
$ ./mygrep ?foo
./mygrep: bad pattern (?foo):
Quantifier follows nothing in regex; marked by <-- HERE in
m/? <-- HERE foo/ at ./mygrep line 10.
```

The main loop is both idiomatic and compact. The `$_` special variable is the default argument for many of Perl's operators, and judicious use helps to emphasize the *what* rather than the how of the implementation's machinery.

I hope these suggestions help!

Comment: Greg, I certainly always use parens in my open examples in my tutorials. I do this because precedence is too hard for me to remember. I always get screwed up with `or` and `//` and stuff, so I just use the C conjunctions that I actually understand.  And therefore I always use parens.  Makes it easier to read, too.

Comment: Can you explain the reason for unshifting "-" in @ARGV in the explanation of <>? I am a Perl beginner. Thanks!

Comment: @Alby Note that it's conditional and happens only when <code>@ARGV</code> is empty. Perl's magic open treats - as a synonym for the standard input, from which the empty filehandle or "diamond operator" reads when no arguments are on the command line.

Comment: Thank you. That explanation clears up my initial confusion of "why put in something that you will take out in the next line?" :)

Answer (score 16):

`my` is for declaring a variable or *a list of them*. It is a common mistake in Perl to write

```
my $var1, $var2, $var3;
```

to declare all of them. The warning should advice you to use the correct form:

```
my ($var1, $var2, $var3);
```

In your example the code does exactly what you want (you didn't get any errors or wrong results, did you?), but to make it absolutely clear you can write

```
open my ($fh), $file;
```

Although one could argue that putting `my` in the middle of line is like hiding it. Maybe more readable:

```
my $fh;
open $fh, $file;
```

Comment: +1 for putting my on its own line...it's easier to notice that way.

Answer (score 2):

To get a more verbose explanation of warning messages, use [perldoc diagnostics](http://perldoc.perl.org/diagnostics.html).
For example,

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use diagnostics;

my $fh, $file;
```

Will generate the following useful explanation:

> Parentheses missing around "my" list 
>       (W parenthesis) You said something like
>
> ```
>     my $foo, $bar = @_;
>
> when you meant
>
>     my ($foo, $bar) = @_;
>
> Remember that "my", "our", and "local" bind tighter than comma.
> ```

You can also look at the documentation for [my](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/my.html) at your command prompt:

```
perldoc -f my
```

> If more than one value is listed, the
>   list must be placed in parentheses.

Answer (score 1):

The real problem is that omitting around function calls is rather fragile. Expect weird errors if you do.

```
$ perl -we'$file="abc"; open(my $fh, $file);'

$ perl -we'$file="abc"; open my $fh, $file;'
Parentheses missing around "my" list at -e line 1.
```

Comment: It is.  I strongly recommend using parens for all function calls.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that your code is longer than it need be - you should employ more laziness.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
my $pattern = shift;
while (<>)
{
    print if m/$pattern/;
}
```

If you decide you need line numbers, or file names (perhaps if there's more than one file), or some other more complicated printing, then you may want to write things out.  But I believe the code I show is equivalent to the code you show.

Normally, I'd add `use strict;` and `use warnings;` to the code.  However, in this example, the only named variable is defined with `my` (so strict won't help), and there's nothing for it to warn about.  However, if you are learning Perl, or if the program is much more complex than this, I would add the `use` lines, even after about 20 years of using Perl.

Answer (score 0):

You may be doing a school or learning project.  But when I want to do something like this is perl, I will usually use this more concise version of your program.

perl -ne 'print if /your_regex/' your_file_list

For more info try

perldoc perlrun

and look for the explanations of -n and -p.